# What tools are available to visualize what methods call other methods for Java code?

Tags: java, visualization

What tools are available to visualize what methods call other methods for Java code?  For example, is there something like CodeDrawer that works with Java?  In particular I'm looking for something that would draw arrows between Obj.methodA() and Obj.methodB() if methodA calls methodB, and maybe organizes a nice star of arrows pointing at methodB from methods that call it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Structure101](http://www.structure101.com), point it at your byte code, select the structure tab, call graph perspective. You can set the depth of calls (both callers and callees) to be displayed, and double clicking on a method will centralize it on the directed graph so that the depth of calls displayed becomes relative to it. A directed graph rather than simple tree is displayed, so that multiple routes between methods can be discovered, such as between `createDetectors`
and `getShortName` in the following (call depth set to 2):

[image]

Comment: What about something not quite so expensive?

Comment: Can Structure101 generate reports? I want to cross-reference it against a list of methods that shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can generate call graphs with doxygen.

Answer (score 0):

If you are OK to use IDEs, then try [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/). It can given caller graph information in a very clean way.

( Netbeans and eclispse will have similar feature)

Comment: how to view graph?